# XCode: Scrollview not scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

so I have added scrollview to my screen.
However, I'm unable to scroll up and down.
My scrollview width and size are 414 and 784 respectively while my content size is        `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 800)`

Why can't I scroll up and down?
How do I fix this?

Comment: seems like content size height is smaller than frame height. You have to add scroll view as full screen subview.

Comment: There's this tutorial here that really should help you understand the basics of scrollview: https://www.appcoda.com/uiscrollview-introduction/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `UIView` (call it content view) inside your `scrollView` with `top`, `botttom`, `left`, `right` constraints to `zero`. And give `height constraint = 800` for this view.

This should work!

Basically, you need to add some content to the `scrollView`. If the height of contents becomes greater than the `scrollView height`, the `scrollView` becomes scrollable.

Comment: if you have top, bottom, left and right constraint, the center vertical/horizontal constraints will do nothing. Pretty good answer otherwise :)